# Error on nova-compute strart - libvirt: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory

Tags: openstack-nova

Any attempt to start nova compute services fails with the error `HypervisorUnavailable: Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host:`

The trace log is the following (taken from `/var/log/nova/nova-compute.log`
)

```
AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting compute node (version 2014.1.1)
ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] Connection to libvirt failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver Traceback (most recent call last):
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 787, in _connect
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver     libvirt.openAuth, uri, auth, flags)
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 139, in proxy_call
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver     rv = execute(f,*args,**kwargs)
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 77, in tworker
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver     rv = meth(*args,**kwargs)
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver     if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver
ERROR nova.openstack.common.threadgroup [-] Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host: <HOST_NAME>
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup Traceback (most recent call last):
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/threadgroup.py", line 117, in wait
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     x.wait()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/threadgroup.py", line 49, in wait
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return self.thread.wait()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 168, in wait
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return self._exit_event.wait()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 116, in wait
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return hubs.get_hub().switch()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 187, in switch
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return self.greenlet.switch()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 194, in main
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     result = function(*args, **kwargs)
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/service.py", line 483, in run_service
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     service.start()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/service.py", line 163, in start
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     self.manager.init_host()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1006, in init_host
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     self.driver.init_host(host=self.host)
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 656, in init_host
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     self._do_quality_warnings()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 639, in _do_quality_warnings
 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     caps = self.get_host_capabilities()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 2849, in get_host_capabilities
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     xmlstr = self._conn.getCapabilities()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 721, in _get_connection
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     wrapped_conn = self._get_new_connection()
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 674, in _get_new_connection
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     wrapped_conn = self._connect(self.uri(), self.read_only)
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 796, in _connect
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     raise exception.HypervisorUnavailable(host=CONF.host)
TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup HypervisorUnavailable: Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host: <HOST_NAME>
```

No other log file indicates any error
`syslog`, `dmesg` and  `/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log` does not show any issue

The libvirt configuration (`/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`) was set to log the errors
`log_outputs="3:syslog:libvirtd"`

Before the error appear the node was running smoothly, no changes were made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it was a miss-configuration of the `libvirt`. In brief the problem was that `libvirtd` was not starting with `--listen` flag and so it was not creating the approiate sock file that the nova service is searching for.

See my relevant [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/610350/368056) on ask ubuntu on how to configure libvirt on 'listen' mode.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had re-installed libvirt and associated packages without restarting `libvirtd`.  The error was thus resolved with the following three commands:

```
systemctl stop libvirtd
systemctl start libvirtd
systemctl status libvirtd
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case last night when I tried to restart my `nova-compute` service .
In the lpg you provided, we can se3 the following line(s)

> Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory TRACE nova.virt.libvirt.driver "

So we can know that the issue results from the `libvirtd` service not working.

In my case I checked the status of `libvirtd` service to find why it fails and then I tried to restart it as depicted bellow

[image]

I googled a lot about the problem (g-io-error-quark,1) above. But all the results are about a problem of /etc/fstab.

In my case, I tried to use the `libvirtd -l` command to get some tips

[image]

Finally I found out that it! The problem is about the `/var/run` and that is a link to path /run and the link fails. So I reset the link to /run ,and then restarted the `libvirtd` service successfully.

I hope this will work to you.